# Why is the word "mitzvos" treated as grammatically masculine in certain prayers?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, mitzvah, grammatical-gender

The prayer accompanying several mitzvos (such as putting on tallis and tefillin) expresses the desire that it be considered that the mitzvah is fulfilled as well as all the "613 mitzvos dependent on it": מצוות התלוים בה.

The word מצוות is normally grammatically feminine, but the word תלוים is masculine in many siddurim, though not all.

A few examples of siddurim that have תלוים:

- ArtScroll Kol Yaakov (Ashkenaz) - p. 2
- ArtScroll Eitz Chaim (Sefard) - p. 2
- The Breslov Siddur (Sefard) - p. 10
- Birnbaum (Ashkenaz) - p. 5
- Koren Siddur Avoteinu (Morocco) - p. 58
- Siddur Avodat Israel (Ashkenaz) - p. 21
- Otzar HaTefillos (Sefard) - p. מג

Examples of siddurim that have תלויות:

- Koren Sacks Siddur (Ashkenaz) - p. 7
- Koren Siddur (Sefard) - p. 4
- Nehalel Siddur (Ashkenaz) - p. 168
- Metsudah (Ashkenaz) - p. 2

On the other hand, in references to the land-dependent mitzvos, I have always seen it as מצוות תלויות בארץ - in the feminine form.

Why does the more common wording have this inconsistency in gender? Is there a deeper meaning?

Comment: Sounds like a grammatical error in the nusah that was kept because of minhag? I know Chabad is very anal about having prays being grammatically correct. Just a thought though, I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete line in that meditation before putting on the tallit says, "May it be considered before You that I accomplished this mitzvah with all of its details (p'rateha) and exact instructions (dikdukeiha) and its proper intentions (kav'nateiha) and the 613 mitzvot that depend on it."  Two of the words in that list are masculine (p'ratim and dikdukim), and therefore the word "taluyim" (depend on, or tied to) must be masculine.  In other words, the word taluyim is referring to the entire list of things which is masculine by force of the inclusion of masculine terms, and does not refer exclusively to the mitzvot, which is feminine.